# Android - onTouch (ACTION_MOVE) - Stop a view from exiting the screen

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, touch-event

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUAEZ.png)I've been stuck for ages on this issue and the internet doesn't appear to want to help either.

I have a custom view which I can drag around the screen using the onTouchListener and events that come with it.  I need this drag to stop when it exits the screen.  I have got the screen dimensions and I can detect when I need something to happen but I can't think of a good way to "force" the view to stay in bounds.

If I set some boolean logic it freezes the view making it unable to drag back away.
If I save points up to that mark and then re-set the view to these when the bounds are detected it looks terrible (jumpy).

I'm looking for the view to stay on the bounds even as the user keeps moving their finger only to come back into "play" when the user drags backwards from the bounds (if you get me?!).  I'm thinking like an imaginary wall...

Relevant code is below so you can get the idea of where I'm at

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams moveParam = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();

                float maxTop = (mHeight-mPeepHole)/2;
                Log.d(TAG, "onTouch: maxTop = " + maxTop);
                if (moveParam.topMargin > maxTop || moveParam.topMargin < -(mHeight-mPeepHole)/2)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onTouch: OUT OF BOUNDS HEIGHT");
                    // this fires when I need it to, all good.
                    // here is where I need some logic

                }

                if (moveParam.leftMargin > (mWidth-mPeepHole)/2 || moveParam.leftMargin < -(mWidth-mPeepHole)/2)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onTouch: OUT OF BOUNDS WIDTH");
                    // and here...
                }

                moveParam.leftMargin = x - Position_X;
                moveParam.topMargin = y - Position_Y;
                moveParam.rightMargin = -500; // ignore this at present
                moveParam.bottomMargin = -500; // ignore this at present
                v.setLayoutParams(moveParam);

                break;
```

...

To elaborate, the x is the centre point which shouldn't be able to exit the screen.  The view can be touched and dragged from any point yet it should always stop when the x hits the screen edge

Answer (score 0):

```
moveParam.leftMargin = Math.max(0,Math.min(screen_width, x - Position_X- view.getWidth()));
```

That would prevent the view from moving off screen at all.  What you're basically doing is no letting the left margin go below 0, or to more than the end of the screen.

Comment: This is good thanks.  However it doesn't work great with my project as it tracks from the user touch input x/y.  My view is full screen so touchable from anywhere but its only the centre point of the screen (width/2, height/2) that I need to contain.

Comment: Then instead of subtracting view width, subtract half that.  And instead of maxing with 0, max with -view.getWidth()/2

Comment: Could you elaborate?  I can't get it to work, although I'm feeling I'm close.  The detection works no matter where I place my finger, but the view will only "stick" when placed exactly in the middle of the screen.